# "objects extracted BY second constraint" or "objects extracted FROM second constraint"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

In the construction below, which preposition is grammatically correct: **by** or **from** (or perhaps something else)?

> As the process particularly runs over the objects extracted
>   **by** second constraint, a circular objects detected by third constraint is not affected.

or

> As the process particularly runs over the objects extracted
>   **from** second constraint, a circular objects detected by third constraint is not affected.

Comment: Can you post a little more context to help us answer your question?  The sentence is not quite grammatically correct no matter what word you use there, and if I understood exactly what was happening in the process it would help me give you a useful answer.

Comment: It's not uncommon to construct sentences in English where more than one preposition will fit just fine, with negligible change in meaning. This could be one of them, but it's hard for us to know, because it's hard for us to envision how an "object" might be "extracted" from (or by, or with) a "constraint." (When I think of objects being extracted, I think of vacuuming my car. When I think of something being extracted via constraints, I think of data tables and filters.) In order for questions like this to be answered, you'll have to give more background information.

Comment: I have trouble making any sense of these two sentences. It's probably all wrong, and choosing a different preposition won't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need further context to actually choose the correct word in this scenario. I will add in both possibilities below, and you can use the one that best fits in with the rest of the paragraph. (also, I've done basic grammar corrections, and added a few words to make the sentences more meaningful)

1. As the process of moulding involves running over the objects extracted from the conveyor belt, the flattening in the tar detected by the computer is not unusual.
2. As the process of moulding involves running over the objects extracted by the conveyor belt, the flattening in the tar detected by the computer is not unusual.

In sentence 1, the objects have been removed from the conveyor belt. ie. It is their point of origin. They were found on the belt, and were then flattened.

In sentence 2, the objects were removed from another (unnamed) source by the conveyor belt, which then carried them away from the parent, and continued the process of flattening.